# Code Complicity issue

Tags: optimization

Write a function:
int solution(int K, int A[], int N);
that, given an integer K and a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns the number of bounded_slices of array A.
If the number of bounded_slices is greater than 1,000,000,000, the function should return 1,000,000,000.
For example, given:
    A[0] = 3
    A[1] = 5
    A[2] = 7
    A[3] = 6
    A[4] = 3
the function should return 9, as explained above.
Assume that:
•        N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
•        K is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000];
•        each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000,000..1,000,000,000].
Complexity:
•        expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
•        expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
*/

my code is not running in O(N) and i want to, any suggestion ??
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */

public int solution(int K, int[] A) 
{
    int numberOfSlices=0;
    ArrayList<Integer>listOfSlices=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
    {
        for( int j=0;j<A.length;j++)
        {
            if((!listOfSlices.contains(A[i])
                &&!listOfSlices.contains(A[j]))&&(max(A[i],A[j])-min(A[i],A[j]))<=K)
            {
              numberOfSlices++;

            }
        }
          listOfSlices.add(A[i]);
    }



    return numberOfSlices;

}

/* return the max between two numbers */
public int max(int p,int q)
{
    if(p>q)
    {
        return p;
    }
    else
    {
        return q;
    }

}

/*return the min between two numbers */
public int min(int p,int q)
{
    if(p<q)
    {
        return p;
    }
    else 
    {
        return q;
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Solution solution=new Solution();
    int[] array={3,5,7,6,3};
    System.out.println("the number of slices in the array is  "+solution.solution(2, array));

}
```

}

Comment: Everyone seems to be asking the same question today.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/21100261/1401351

Comment: if you have any suggestion it will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is still active so nobody will give too much away, but I'll point you in the right direction (or at least, away from the wrong direction).

Nesting for loops is risky; as is, you're basically guaranteeing O(N^2). You need to find a way to reduce your pool, rather than iterate again for each element.

Still, as you have it, this is going to fail a lot of test cases. If a brute force is failing, it means you're missing a way to handle some [corner cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case). like the problem warns in the full description.

So:

1) Recognize that brute forcing is exponentially slower than required, think about how you could reduce what you need to search.

2) Write out some wacky test cases and find where and *why* your code fails, then reconsider your solution. The answer won't be an if statement for every case.

Your code definitely fails (6, [4, 5, 8, 5, 1, 4, 6, 8, 7, 2, 2, 5]), which should return 44. Consider that test case.

Good luck.